# Name of cached images using universal image loader

Tags: image, caching, universal

I'm caching images using Universal Image Loader, but I need save images with the name I want and I dont Know how can I do it.

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisc(true)
        .build();


ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())

        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
    .memoryCacheSize(41943040)
    .discCacheSize(104857600)
    .threadPoolSize(10)
    .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

and I display Image:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(fileObject.getUrl(), imgPromo);
```

This save image in sdcard/android/mypackage/cache/uil-images with a name by default(I think), but I need that the image's name is "myimage" for example.

thanks!!